# How do I remove the b'' prefix in a str variable with unicode escapes in python?

Tags: python, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I know that using this code can remove the b prefix

```py
>>> b'Hello'
b'Hello'
>>> b'Hello'.decode() # decodes bytes type
'Hello'
```

But if I use a unicode escape (with `unicode_escape` codec because the `utf-8` codec struggles), it works fine... [Python 3.10, Windows 10, AMD64]

```py
>>> b'Hello\xeb'.decode() # utf-8 codec does not work that well
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    b'Hello\xeb'.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 5: unexpected end of data
>>> b'Hello\xeb'.decode('unicode_escape')
'Helloë'
```

...but for example if I use a `.exe` file it does not work (and the `b` prefix is still there??)

```py
>>> # some thing that reads file, code: with open('autoclicker.exe', 'rb') ...
b'MZ\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x01\x00\x00\x0e\x1f\xba\x0e\x00\xb4\t\xcd!\xb8\x01L\xcd!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.\r\r\n$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x82\xc1\xedi\xe3\xaf\xbei\xe3\xaf\xbei\xe3\xaf\xbe\xd4\xac9\xbek\xe3\xaf\xbe`\x9b:\xbew\xe3\xaf\xbe`\x9b,\xbe\xdb\xe3\xaf\xbe`\x9b+\xbeP\xe3\xaf\xbeN%\xc2\xbec\xe3\xaf\xbeN%\xd4\xbeH\xe3\xaf\xbei\xe3\xae\xbed\xe1\xaf\xbe`\x9b \xbe/\xe3\xaf\xbew\xb1:\xbek\xe3\xaf\xbew\xb1;\xbeh\xe3\xaf\xbei\xe38\xbeh\xe3\xaf\xbe`\x9b>\xbeh\xe3\xaf\xbeRichi\xe3\xaf\xbe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00PE\x00\x00L\x01\x04\x00\x14\xb3\x8a\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x00#\x01\x0b\x01\t\x00\x00\x02\x08\x00\x00\xf0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10c\x01\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00 \x08\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x0b\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x03\t\x0e\x00\x02\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xcd\x08\x00T\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb0\n\x00\xfc\xac\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x08\x00@\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.text\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x08\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x02\x08\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00`.rdata\x00\x00\\\xd9\x00\x00\x00 \x08\x00\x00\xda\x00\x00\x00\x06\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@.data\x00\x00\x00\x18\xa5\x01\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\xc0.rsrc\x00\x00\x00\xfc\xac\x00\x00\x00\xb0\n\x00\x00\xae\x00\x00\x00H\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\xc0\x81\xec\xac\x03\x00\x008\x05\x92rI\x00tCh\xa4\x03\x00\x00P\x8dT$\x0cR\xa2\x92rI\x00\x89\x81\x8c\x01\x00\x00\xe8\xc5!\x01\x00\xa1\xc0rI\x00\x83\xc4\x0c\x8d\x0c$Qj\x02\xc7D$\x08\xa8\x03\x00\x00\x89D$\x0c\xc7D$\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\x15\x8c$H\x00\x81\xc4\xac\x03\x00\x00\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x8bF$S3\xdb;\xc3\x0f\x85J\x85\x02\x00\x8bF,\x89^$;\xc3\x0f\x85J\x85\x02\x00\x89^,\x89^0\x89^4\x89^8\x88^\x10[\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\x80~\t\x00\x0f\x85\x95\x82\x02\x00j\x08\xe8y\x06\x01\x00\x83\xc4\x04\x85\xc0t\x10\x8b\x17\x89\x10\x8bN\x04\x89H\x04\xff\x06\x89F\x04\xc3\x8bN\x043\xc0\x89H\x04\xff\x06\x89F\x04\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x8bD$\x10\x8bL$\x0cS\x8b\\$\x08W\x8b|$\x10PQ\xe8\x07\x00\x00\x00_[\xc2\x10\x00\xcc\xccU\x8b\xec\x83\xe4\xf8QV;\x1d\xc0rI\x00uP\x81\xff\x11\x01\x00\x00s(\x83\xff\x12r#;=\x80\x93J\x00\x0f\x84r\xd6\x02\x00\x8bU\x0c\x8bE\x08RPWS\xff\x15\x84&H\x00^\x8b\xe5]\xc2\x08\x00\x81\xff\x13\x01\x00\x00u#\x8bE\x08h\xb8\x84J\x00\x8b\xf3\xe8\xe9\x00\x00\x003\xc0^\x8b\xe5]\xc2\x08\x00\xa1\xc0rI\x00\x85\xc0t\xa7\xeb\xbe\x83\xff\x10w9\x0f\x84\xa5\xd5\x02\x00\x8dG\xff\x83\xf8\x06w\x9f\xff$\x85\x14\x12@\x00j\x01S\xff\x15\xd0&H\x00\xb9\xb8\x84J\x00\xe8x\xfe\xff\xffj\x00\xff\x15\xcc&H\x003\xc0^\x8b\xe5]\xc2\x08\x00\x81\xff\x12\x03\x00\x00wa\x0f\x84\xc9\xd5\x02\x00\x83\xff\x11\x0f\x84\x90\xd5\x02\x00\x81\xff\x11\x01\x00\x00\x0f\x85Q\xff\xff\xff\xe9`\xd5\x02\x00j\x00h\xee\x02\x00\x00j\x01S\xff\x15\xdc&H\x00hhHH\x00\xff\x15\xd8&H\x00\x83=\xb8\x84J\x00\x00\xa3\x80\x93J\x00\x0f\x85Y\xff\xff\xff\xff\x15\xd4&H\x00\xa3\xb8\x84J\x003\xc0^\x8b\xe5]\xc2\x08\x00\x81\xff\x01\x04\x00\x00\x0f\x85\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xe9\x9e\xd5\x02\x00\x90\xc1\x11@\x00u\x11@\x00\r\x11@\x00\r\x11@\x00\xe7\xe6B\x00\r\x11@\x00\xd6\xe6B\x00\x81\xec\xa8\x03\x00\x00\x83\xe8\x01SW\x0f\x85\x84\x00\x00\x00h\xa4\x03\x00\x00P\x8dX\x01\x8dD$\x14P\xc7D$\x14\xa8\x03\x00\x00\xe8\x94\x1f\x01\x00\x8b\x84$\xc0\x03\x00\x00\x83\xc4\x0c\xe8\x05\x0c\x00\x00\x80=\x92rI\x00\x00t:\x80=\x94rI\x00\x00\x8b\xbc$\xb4\x03\x00\x00\x89t$\x0c\x89\\$\x10\xc7D$\x14\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x85\xc9\x97\x02\x00\x80\x7f\t\x00\x0f\x85\n\x98\x02\x008\x9f\x84\x01\x00\x00\x0f\x84J\x98\x02\x00SV\xff\x15\xd0&H\x00j\x00h\xee\x02\x00\x00SV\xff\x15\xdc&H\x00_[\x81\xc4\xa8\x03\x00\x00\xc2\x04\x00\x8b\x03\x85\xc0t\tP\xe8\x13\x00\x01\x00\x83\xc4\x04V\x8d\xb3\xec\x00\x00\x00W\xc7\x06p\xa0H\x00\xe8\x1e\xf5\x00\x00\x8bF\x04P\xe8\xf4\xff\x00\x00\x83\xc4\x04\x8d\x8b\xbc\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x17\x13\x00\x00\x8d{x\xe8O\x00\x00\x00\x8d{4\xe8G\x00\x00\x00\x8dK$\xe8\xff\x12\x00\x00_\x8dK\x14^\xe9\xf5\x12\x00\x00\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x8bF\x0c\xff\x08\x8bF\x0c\x838\x00u\x14\x8b\x0eQ\xe8\xaa\xff\x00\x00\x8bV\x0cR\xe8\xa1\xff\x00\x00\x83\xc4\x08\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xccV\x8b\xf7\xe8\xf8\xfc\xff\xff\x8dw\x14\xe8\xc0\xff\xff\xff\x8b\xf7\xe8\xb9\xff\xff\xff^\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x8b\x06\x85\xc0t\tP\xe8c\xff\x00\x00\x83\xc4\x04W\x8d\xbe\xec\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xc5\xff\xff\xff\x8d\x8e\xbc\x00\x00\x00\xe8z\x12\x00\x00\x8d\x8e\xac\x00\x00\x00\xe8o\x12\x00\x00\x8d\x8e\x9c\x00\x00\x00\xe8d\x12\x00\x00\x8d\x8e\x8c\x00\x00\x00\xe8Y\x12\x00\x00\x8d~\x08\xe8\xd1\xf0\x00\x00_\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xccj\x04\xe83\x03\x01\x00\x83\xc4\x04\x85\xc0\x0f\x84\xc2\x82\x02\x00\xc7\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x89F\x0c\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xccV\x8b\xf1@3\xc9\x89F\x08\xba\x02\x00\x00\x00\xf7\xe2\x0f\x90\xc1\xc7F\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf7\xd9\x0b\xc8Q\xe8\xf6\x02\x01\x003\xc9\x89\x06\x83\xc4\x04f\x89\x08\xe8\xad\xff\xff\xff\x8b\xc6^\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x81\xec\x14\x02\x00\x00\xe8\x85\x13\x00\x00\x84\xc0\x0f\x84n\xae\x02\x00\xe8\x98\x00\x00\x00\x85\xc0\x0f\x85a\xae\x02\x00\xe8k\xc1\x00\x00\x85\xc0\x0f\x85T\xae\x02\x00\x8b\x94$\x18\x02\x00\x00\x8d\x04$P\x8dL$\x08Qh\x04\x01\x00\x00R\xff\x15 #H\x00\x8dD$\x04P\xb8\xe8\x7fJ\x00\xe8H\r\x00\x00\x8b\x0c$Q\xb8\xd8\x7fJ\x00\xe8:\r\x00\x00\x8b\x04$3\xd2f\x89P\xfef9T$\x08\x0f\x84\x11\xae\x02\x00\x8dT$\x04R\xb8\xf8\x7fJ\x00\xe8\x17\r\x00\x00\x8b\x84$\x1c\x02\x00\x00\xa3\xd4\x7fJ\x003\xc0\x81\xc4\x14\x02\x00\x00\xc2\x08\x00\x8b@\x04\x85\xc0\x0f\x85\xb4\x81\x02\x00\xc3\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x83\xect3\xc0SUVW\xbd\x01\x00\x00\x00\x89D$\x18\x89D$,\x89D$0\x89D$$\x89D$ \x89D$\x1c\x89D ...
>>> b'hi\xbd'.decode('unicode_escape') # using some (unicode) escape methods work separately
'hi½'
>>> b'abc\'
```

Comment: just strip it off   `print(repr(my_bytes)[2:-1])`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Works okay, but some chars dont turn into the acutal chars (\xbd---> ë, instead, \xbd ---> \xbd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `b''` isn't a "string prefix", instead it indicates that you are dealing with a sequence of bytes. Bytes can represent anything, including a text which is just a series of characters in some encoding, like UTF-8, ASCII, etc.

That's what `.decode()` does, it takes the sequence of bytes and interprets it as if it were a string of characters in that encoding and returns a string of those characters. Conversely, you could then encode the resulting string of characters into some other encoding by calling `.encode()` on the string and you'd get the sequence of bytes that represents that string in that encoding.

However, you can't just take any sequence of bytes and 'decode' it as any decoding - the bytes will have a certain encoding if they represent some string, but the example you give (of an executable) doesn't represent a string of characters at all and thus won't successfully decode into a string if you just call `.decode()` on it.

If you're lucky, the decoding works on the parts of the executable that are strings in that encoding, but even that's not guaranteed to work, as the strings will be surrounded by bytes that don't represent that encoding.

If you want to extract strings from an executable, you need to correctly identify what parts of the executable represent strings, extract those sequences of bytes and decode them with the correct encoding. How to do that will depend on the operating system the executable is for, whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit, etc.

Note: many programmers new to Python or coding in general get confused by the fact that Python (for the sake of convenience) shows you a bytes object as very similar to a string (it looks just like string with a `b` before it), this is even more confusing if it happens to be an encoding that's UTF or very similar, as the contents of the bytes object will even be readable then. But that doesn't mean the bytes objects actually *is* a string.

Comment: Thank you - I have always been confused by encoding vs bytes/string :\

Comment: Okay... So it's complicated and platform dependent

Comment: @Allearthstuffs as far as getting text from executable binaries goes, yes. What exactly were you hoping to do? Perhaps the specific problem you're trying to solve isn't as hard.